# Does G41 chipset support virtualization?

Tags: hardware-virtualization

I'm confused because [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Intel_chipsets) it clearly says that Intel G41 chipset does NOT support
Hardware Virtualization. However, from GA-EP41T-UD3L manual, which has G41, I see that its bios has Virtualization setting, which is enabled and in the note I see that if CPU supports this feature then it can also support. So I'm confused and the question is does GA-EP41T-UD3L support HW virtualization or not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While what Wikipedia has listed as "No" is hardware virtualization (referring to [Intel's VT-d technology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_VT-d#I.2FO_MMU_virtualization_.28AMD-Vi_and_VT-d.29)), [your motherboard's manual](http://download.gigabyte.ru/manual/mb_manual_ga-ep41t-ud3l_e.pdf) (which does not mention hardware virtualization, but only "Virtualization Technology") actually refers to enabling/disabling *processor* virtualization ([Intel's VT-x technology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_VT-d#Intel_virtualization_.28VT-x.29)).

The two are fundamentally different, so to avoid confusion, I will use Intel's VT nomenclature from now on.

Intel's VT-x allows a virtual machine's code to run directly on a CPU, which your motherboard *does* have support for.  Intel's VT-d allows direct access to the chipset's I/O lines (through an actual hardware interface, which [your motherboard does not have](http://www.intel.com/Assets/PDF/specupdate/319971.pdf)), which provide [DMA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_memory_access) support and direct hardware access (instead of emulated).

So in summary, your motherboard **does** support VT-x (*processor virtualization*), but it **does not** support VT-d (*hardware virtualization*).